# How does PouchDB respond to Couch DB Validations Errors?

Tags: pouchdb

I was curious if PouchDB will persist a document change when CouchDB throws a validation error. And if so do we have to clean up the data if it was still persisted in PouchDB? Or is that done automatically for us?

Comment: From my initial testing of this, it appears that pouchdb still persists the documents locally. But somehow the errors are getting swallowed up. And in the indexdb database locally, it's indicated that they synced. This is not what I expected.

Comment: If CouchDB is rejecting documents during replication due to validation errors, these will be perceived as replication errors. Replication errors would never result in PouchDB deleting or modifying a document. You could potentially listen to the replication errors, and handle them appropriately for your app at that level.

Comment: @Flimzy Thank you for the insight into this matter. Really appreciate your response.

Comment: @Flimzy I found that listening for errors on 'sync' does not work. But that listening for errors on 'replicate.to' does work. And that for a 'denied' event to be emitted the thrown error has to have a 'forbidden' property on it. Otherwise it result in an 'unknown error' that emits the 'pause' event over and over.